# Edges of SVG are getting cut off in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

On firefox the left edges of these SVGs are getting cut off at a certain windows size:
[image: SVG cut off]

In Chrome its working. Does anybody knows why this is happening?
Some Firefox-internal bug? I already removed all styles from the svg, but its still not working. Setting the width to 100% isn't working either.

Contact SVG Source Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="77px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 77 30" enable-background="new 0 0 77 30" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#333333" d="M0,15c0,7.95,6.18,14.45,14,14.97c0.33,0.02,0.66,0.03,1,0.03h46
    v-0.03c0.33,0.02,0.66,0.03,1,0.03c8.28,0,15-6.72,15-15S70.28,0,62,0c-0.34,0-0.67,0.01-1,0.03V0H15c-0.34,0-0.67,0.01-1,0.03
    C6.18,0.55,0,7.05,0,15z M14,29.97V30h1C14.66,30,14.33,29.99,14,29.97z M15,0h-1v0.03C14.33,0.01,14.66,0,15,0z"/>
<g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M14.59,17.11c0.22,0.62,0.52,1.16,0.91,1.58
        c0.38,0.43,0.83,0.76,1.36,0.98c0.53,0.22,1.09,0.33,1.72,0.33c0.62,0,1.19-0.11,1.69-0.34c0.48-0.22,0.92-0.55,1.31-0.99
        l-0.7-0.76c-0.32,0.36-0.66,0.62-1.02,0.81C19.5,18.91,19.08,19,18.61,19c-0.47,0-0.89-0.09-1.27-0.28
        c-0.37-0.19-0.7-0.45-0.95-0.81c-0.26-0.35-0.47-0.77-0.61-1.27c-0.15-0.48-0.22-1.05-0.22-1.67c0-0.6,0.07-1.14,0.22-1.64
        c0.16-0.49,0.36-0.91,0.64-1.25c0.27-0.35,0.6-0.61,0.97-0.8C17.77,11.09,18.2,11,18.67,11c0.42,0,0.8,0.09,1.11,0.25
        c0.31,0.16,0.6,0.37,0.86,0.66l0.7-0.8c-0.29-0.28-0.67-0.55-1.11-0.77C19.78,10.12,19.25,10,18.66,10c-0.63,0-1.22,0.12-1.75,0.34
        c-0.53,0.24-1,0.57-1.39,1c-0.39,0.44-0.69,0.96-0.91,1.58c-0.22,0.63-0.33,1.31-0.33,2.08C14.28,15.78,14.38,16.48,14.59,17.11z"
        />
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M24.61,15.5c0.09-0.31,0.23-0.58,0.42-0.8
        c0.19-0.22,0.41-0.39,0.67-0.51c0.25-0.13,0.55-0.19,0.86-0.19c0.32,0,0.6,0.06,0.86,0.19c0.25,0.12,0.47,0.29,0.66,0.51
        c0.19,0.22,0.33,0.49,0.44,0.8c0.09,0.31,0.15,0.64,0.15,1.02c0,0.37-0.06,0.71-0.15,1.01c-0.11,0.31-0.25,0.56-0.44,0.78
        c-0.19,0.22-0.41,0.39-0.66,0.52C27.16,18.95,26.88,19,26.56,19c-0.31,0-0.61-0.05-0.86-0.17c-0.26-0.13-0.48-0.3-0.67-0.52
        c-0.19-0.22-0.33-0.47-0.42-0.78c-0.09-0.3-0.14-0.64-0.14-1.01C24.47,16.14,24.52,15.81,24.61,15.5z M23.47,18
        c0.19,0.44,0.42,0.8,0.73,1.09c0.32,0.3,0.68,0.52,1.08,0.68c0.41,0.15,0.83,0.23,1.28,0.23c0.44,0,0.88-0.08,1.28-0.23
        c0.41-0.16,0.77-0.38,1.08-0.68c0.31-0.29,0.55-0.65,0.74-1.09c0.18-0.44,0.28-0.92,0.28-1.48c0-0.57-0.1-1.05-0.28-1.49
        c-0.19-0.44-0.43-0.8-0.74-1.11c-0.31-0.3-0.67-0.53-1.08-0.69C27.44,13.08,27,13,26.56,13c-0.45,0-0.87,0.08-1.28,0.23
        c-0.4,0.16-0.76,0.39-1.08,0.69c-0.31,0.31-0.54,0.67-0.73,1.11c-0.19,0.44-0.28,0.92-0.28,1.49C23.19,17.08,23.28,17.56,23.47,18z
        "/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M31.73,20h1.22v-4.98c0.38-0.33,0.71-0.58,1-0.75
        c0.28-0.18,0.63-0.27,1-0.27c0.47,0,0.83,0.16,1.05,0.44c0.22,0.28,0.33,0.75,0.33,1.39V20h1.23v-4.33c0-0.87-0.18-1.55-0.53-2
        C36.67,13.23,36.11,13,35.34,13c-0.51,0-0.96,0.11-1.34,0.3c-0.39,0.18-0.75,0.43-1.09,0.72h-0.05L32.75,13h-1.02V20z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M39.94,17.75c0,0.34,0.03,0.64,0.11,0.92
        c0.06,0.28,0.18,0.52,0.34,0.7c0.16,0.21,0.38,0.36,0.64,0.47c0.27,0.11,0.6,0.16,1,0.16c0.22,0,0.45-0.02,0.69-0.08l0.66-0.19
        l-0.24-0.92c-0.12,0.06-0.26,0.11-0.42,0.14C42.56,18.98,42.44,19,42.31,19c-0.42,0-0.72-0.11-0.87-0.33
        c-0.17-0.22-0.25-0.55-0.25-0.97V14h1.97v-1h-1.97v-2.03h-1.03L40,13l-1.14,0.08V14h1.08V17.75z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M45.75,17.8c0.11-0.13,0.3-0.25,0.55-0.35
        c0.25-0.09,0.59-0.18,1.01-0.26c0.41-0.07,0.92-0.13,1.55-0.19v1.19c-0.36,0.28-0.69,0.48-1,0.61c-0.31,0.14-0.66,0.2-1,0.2
        c-0.38,0-0.67-0.05-0.92-0.17c-0.25-0.13-0.36-0.33-0.36-0.61C45.58,18.06,45.63,17.92,45.75,17.8z M44.97,19.55
        c0.41,0.31,0.92,0.45,1.55,0.45c0.43,0,0.87-0.08,1.28-0.23c0.4-0.16,0.78-0.35,1.14-0.58h0.01L49.06,20h1.02v-4.19
        c0-0.84-0.2-1.53-0.6-2.04c-0.4-0.5-1.04-0.77-1.93-0.77c-0.6,0-1.13,0.11-1.63,0.31c-0.5,0.21-0.9,0.41-1.23,0.61l0.5,0.86
        c0.28-0.19,0.59-0.37,0.97-0.53c0.36-0.16,0.76-0.25,1.2-0.25c0.3,0,0.55,0.06,0.73,0.17c0.19,0.13,0.33,0.27,0.46,0.45
        c0.11,0.19,0.18,0.41,0.23,0.65c0.05,0.25,0.08,0.48,0.08,0.73c-1.56,0.16-2.7,0.41-3.42,0.75c-0.72,0.36-1.06,0.87-1.06,1.53
        C44.38,18.83,44.56,19.25,44.97,19.55z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M52.45,18c0.18,0.44,0.41,0.8,0.72,1.09
        c0.3,0.3,0.66,0.52,1.08,0.68c0.42,0.15,0.88,0.23,1.36,0.23c0.44,0,0.86-0.08,1.27-0.25c0.4-0.16,0.76-0.39,1.1-0.67l-0.56-0.81
        c-0.22,0.2-0.48,0.37-0.76,0.51c-0.28,0.16-0.6,0.22-0.94,0.22c-0.34,0-0.64-0.05-0.92-0.17c-0.28-0.13-0.53-0.3-0.72-0.52
        c-0.19-0.22-0.35-0.47-0.45-0.78c-0.11-0.3-0.16-0.64-0.16-1.01c0-0.38,0.05-0.71,0.17-1.02c0.11-0.31,0.27-0.58,0.47-0.8
        c0.19-0.22,0.44-0.39,0.72-0.51c0.28-0.13,0.58-0.19,0.92-0.19c0.28,0,0.55,0.06,0.78,0.19c0.24,0.12,0.47,0.26,0.69,0.45
        l0.61-0.78c-0.25-0.22-0.55-0.42-0.89-0.59C56.59,13.09,56.17,13,55.7,13c-0.47,0-0.92,0.08-1.34,0.23
        c-0.44,0.16-0.81,0.39-1.13,0.69c-0.31,0.31-0.57,0.67-0.76,1.11c-0.19,0.44-0.28,0.92-0.28,1.49C52.19,17.08,52.27,17.56,52.45,18
        z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M59.94,17.75c0,0.34,0.03,0.64,0.11,0.92
        c0.06,0.28,0.18,0.52,0.34,0.7c0.16,0.21,0.38,0.36,0.64,0.47c0.27,0.11,0.6,0.16,1,0.16c0.22,0,0.45-0.02,0.69-0.08l0.66-0.19
        l-0.24-0.92c-0.12,0.06-0.26,0.11-0.42,0.14C62.56,18.98,62.44,19,62.31,19c-0.42,0-0.72-0.11-0.87-0.33
        c-0.17-0.22-0.25-0.55-0.25-0.97V14h1.97v-1h-1.97v-2.03h-1.03L60,13l-1.14,0.08V14h1.08V17.75z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

The website is made with wordpress, so the SVG's are getting implemented by wordpress.
I probably could fix that, by adjusting the view size of the SVG's, but i would have to do that with js and thats pretty dirty.

Comment: please try `svg{overflow: visible;}`

Comment: Hard to know what's going on since you've elided all the path d attributes. That's pretty key information here.

Comment: I already tried overflow: visible - it did not worked.

Comment: @RobertLongson I just added the full svg path data. I thought, that the problem would be more something like a firefox bug or so than having to do something with the svg. Because if i scale the svgs bigger its on their own they are being displayed right.

Comment: Doesn't look cut off to me.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked `svg {overflow: visible;}` . So far spotted this issue in Firefox only.